# MKAnnotationView image property

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkannotationview

I have an `MKAnnotationView` (`draggable` property is set to `YES`) with a custom image,  set via the `image` property. When the annotation is added to the map it has the custom image. But the image turns back to the default pin when the annotation is dragged. I also  tried to overwrite the `image` propery everytime the `dragState` changes. No  luck here also.

Answer (score 5):

You're using an MKPinAnnotationView instance instead of using an MKAnnotationView instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `MKAnnotationView`, not a `MKPinAnnotationView`. Also consider my answer on your other question regarding dragging. Pretty cool stuff.

An `MKPinAnnotationView` is a ready made annotation view, just like the `MKPointAnnotation` is a concrete implementation of the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

These two classes could be used together to get quick, uncustomised results.

I believe you may be using `MKPinAnnotationView` which will always default to a pin as it's lifecycle occurs.